# Warning: mysql_connect(): [2002] No such file or directory (trying to connect via unix:///tmp/mysql.sock) in

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to connect to my MySQL DB with the Terminal on my Apple (With PHP).

Yesterday it worked fine, and now I suddenly get the error in the title.

The script works when I use my browser to run it (I have XAMPP installed), but Terminal refuses to connect to the DB.

Here is the file that I include to connect (the script works when I don't include this, but then it doesn't connect to the DB):

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("FNB1C_data") or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

That should work, since it works with my browser.

The command I use at the Terminal is `php scriptname.php`.

Answer (score 420):

For some reason mysql on OS X gets the locations of the required socket file a bit wrong, but thankfully the solution is as simple as setting up a symbolic link.

You may have a socket (appearing as a zero length file) as `/tmp/mysql.sock` or `/var/mysql/mysql.sock`, but one or more apps is looking in the other location for it. Find out with this command:

```
ls -l /tmp/mysql.sock /var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Rather than move the socket, edit config files, and have to remember to keep edited files local and away from servers where the paths are correct, simply create a symbolic link so your Mac finds the required socket, even when it's looking in the wrong place!

If you have `/tmp/mysql.sock` but no `/var/mysql/mysql.sock` then...

```
cd /var 
sudo mkdir mysql
sudo chmod 755 mysql
cd mysql
sudo ln -s /tmp/mysql.sock mysql.sock
```

If you have `/var/mysql/mysql.sock` but no `/tmp/mysql.sock` then...

```
cd /tmp
ln -s /var/mysql/mysql.sock mysql.sock
```

You will need permissions to create the directory and link, so just prefix the commands above with sudo if necessary.

Comment: Good answer. Fix worked for me. Do you know why it might work once and then not work again?  I had that same problem.

Comment: This is rather hacky. I much rather recommend @luismreis' answer to work around that MySQL hidden shortcut.

Comment: Did not work for me... I haven't any of those files. But the luismreis' answer worked!

Comment: @MattiSG luismreis'answer did not work for me... this one did.

Comment: This is not "hacky". It is the correct way to get the `localhost` socket to work, and it may be of importance if you don't want the extra overhead from sending packets to the router before the database is accessed.

Comment: The path on my Ubuntu 10.04 was not correct. I had to do this: `cd /tmp` and then: `sudo ln -s /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock mysql.sock`.

Comment: Mine was first sketched situation right after a fresh install of mysql. Solution worked!

Comment: This is a php.ini configuration issue, @noun's answer is the correct approach. This answer is a fudge.

Comment: Thanks for this, saved me a lot of time.  Why is it so broken in OSX?

Comment: I moved from MacPorts to Homebrew for MySQL and had the wrong symlink `mysql.sock -> /opt/local/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock` at `/var/mysql`. Changed it by running `ln -s /tmp/mysql.sock mysql.sock` as suggested here and all good now!

Comment: +1 This worked well for me -- thanks. I just wonder why you didn't have `sudo` in front of the `ln -s`, when you had it in front of `mkdir` and `chmod`. Seems to me the `ln` requires it just as much as the others.

Comment: $ sudo su -

to change user to root mode.

Answer (score 375):

I also had this error, but could only fix it through the suggestion [here](http://webdevjourney.wordpress.com/2011/04/20/warning-mysql_connect-function-mysql-connect-no-such-file-or-directory/).

To summarize, use:

```
127.0.0.1
```

Instead of:

```
localhost
```

The reason is that "localhost" is a special name for the MySQL driver making it use the UNIX socket to connect to MySQL instead of the a TCP socket.

Comment: If this works, then check your `hosts` file, it might be missing or messed up

Comment: also maybe good to mention: When using MAMP like me you have to uncheck the box "Allow local access only"

Comment: This solution makes extra overhead as the packet is sent by the router first. Usually not a big problem while testing, but it may become a problem with large packets of data.

Comment: @Kebman that's non sense. The 127.0.0.1 interface does not make packets pass thru any router at all. Just try a traceroute 127.0.0.1

Comment: @Fabrizio No, it is not related. When you use localhost as name, mysql will use a Unix socket instead that is handled through a file entry (mysql.sock, for example), not an Inet one, no matter if localhost is declared in /etc/hosts or not. However, when you use an ip address instead, even 127.0.0.1, you force mysql to open an Inet socket instead.

Comment: Does this then, imply that all the grants you provided on the MySQL db to 'user'%'localhost' will break?

Comment: @Kebman, can you explain more about why the packet would be sent by the router first, and what that means (first before what)?

Comment: Please put it clearly by saying something like use "127.0.0.1" in your mysql_connect instead of "localhost". Otherwise this worked for me, +1.

Comment: Not really a goer if you use virtual hosts, or like to name your test web-pages in /etc/hosts - far better to use a solution like @noun below and edit the php.ini file to point to the correct socket

Comment: This is a great answer, thanks. Using "localhost" instead of "127.0.0.1" was causing a strange problem with cli_dispatch.php of my typo3 installation (`Uncaught TYPO3 Exception #1270853884: TYPO3 Fatal Error: The current username, password or host was not accepted when the connection to the database was attempted to be established!`). Thanks to your answer this is fixed now.

Answer (score 25):

I was having the same problem and this is how I fixed it:

I had this and it didn't work:

```
$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '1234');
```

I did this and it worked:

```
$con = mysql_connect(':/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock', 'root', '1234');
```

Instead of using the mysql server, I connected directly to the Unix Socket. Worked for me.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me also. I don't have a /var/mysql/mysql.sock. And I don't have a /tmp/mysql.sock.

Comment: did you try 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost ?

Answer (score 22):

MySQL socket is located, in general, in `/tmp/mysql.sock` or `/var/mysql/mysql.sock`, but probably PHP looks in the wrong place.

1. Check where is your socket with:

   ```
    sudo /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb
   ```
2. When the updatedb is terminated:

   ```
    locate mysql.sock
   ```
3. Then locate your php.ini:

   ```
    php -i | grep php.ini
   ```

   this will output something like:

   ```
    Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /opt/local/etc/php54
    Loaded Configuration File => /opt/local/etc/php54/php.ini
   ```
4. Edit your php.ini

   ```
    sudo vim /opt/local/etc/php54/php.ini
   ```
5. Change the lines:

   ```
    pdo_mysql.default_socket=/tmp/mysql.sock
    mysql.default_socket=/tmp/mysql.sock
    mysqli.default_socket = /tmp/mysql.sock
   ```

   where /tmp/mysql.sock is the path to your socket.
6. Save your modifications and exit ESC + SHIFT: x
7. Restart Apache

   ```
    sudo apachectl stop
    sudo apachectl start
   ```

Comment: I don't have a php.ini; I only have a php.ini.default, so it appears that the workaround here is necessary: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/65802/which-php-ini-file-do-i-have-to-edit-on-mountain-lion  However, it did not work for me.

Comment: @user124384 Your installation is probably broken: rename your `php.ini.default` to `php.ini`.

Comment: Apache can be restarted with a single line: `sudo apachectl restart`

Answer (score 13):

I am on XAMPP on Mac OS X, and **Brian Lowe's solution above worked with a slight modification**.

The mysql.sock file is actually in "/Applications/xampp/xamppfiles/var/mysql/" folder. So had to link it up both in /tmp and /var/mysql. I haven't checked which one is used by PHP command line, but this did the fix, so I am happy :-)

```
sudo su
ln -s /Applications/xampp/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock /tmp/mysql.sock
mkdir /var/mysql
ln -s /Applications/xampp/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock /var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Comment: ty - I searched few days for a solution and this is the one that finally made things right! =)
XAMPP on OS X too

Answer (score 11):

Mac OS X EL Capitan + MAMP Pro
Do this

```
cd /var
sudo mkdir mysql
sudo chmod 755 mysql
cd mysql
sudo ln -s /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock mysql.sock
```

Then do this

```
cd /tmp
sudo ln -s /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock mysql.sock
```

Hope this saves you some time.

Comment: It's linking the `mysql.dock` in the `/tmp` that solved it. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

When you face the following issue:

> PHP throwing error "Warning: mysql_connect() http://function.mysql-connect: 2002 No such file or directory (trying to connect via unix:///tmp/mysql.sock)"

Set "mysql.default_socket" value in your `/etc/php.ini` to

```
 "mysql.default_socket = /var/mysql/mysql.sock".
```

Then restart web service in server admin

Comment: This was the best answer for me - in my case I am using MAMP, I added to my php.ini: mysqli.default_socket = /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
mysql.default_socket = /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock

Answer (score 6):

The reason is that php cannot find the correct path of `mysql.sock`.

Please make sure that your mysql is running first.

Then, please confirm that which path is the `mysql.sock` located, for example `/tmp/mysql.sock`

then add this path string to php.ini:

- mysql.default_socket = /tmp/mysql.sock
- mysqli.default_socket = /tmp/mysql.sock
- pdo_mysql.default_socket = /tmp/mysql.sock

Finally, restart Apache.

Answer (score 4):

Fix the looming 2002 socket error – which is linking where MySQL places the socket and where OSX thinks it should be, MySQL puts it in /tmp and OSX looks for it in /var/mysql the socket is a type of file that allows mysql client/server communication.

```
sudo mkdir /var/mysql
```

and then

```
sudo ln -s /tmp/mysql.sock /var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

source: http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-phpmyadmin-working-osx-10-10-yosemite/

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to fix the socket location in the php.ini configuration file like this:

```
pdo_mysql.default_socket=/tmp/mysql.sock
```

Of course, the symlink works too, so its a matter of preference which one you change.

Answer (score 1):

When you install php53-mysql using port it returns the following message which is the solution to this problem:

```
To use mysqlnd with a local MySQL server, edit /opt/local/etc/php53/php.ini
and set mysql.default_socket, mysqli.default_socket and
pdo_mysql.default_socket to the path to your MySQL server's socket file.

For mysql5, use /opt/local/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock
For mysql51, use /opt/local/var/run/mysql51/mysqld.sock
For mysql55, use /opt/local/var/run/mysql55/mysqld.sock
For mariadb, use /opt/local/var/run/mariadb/mysqld.sock
For percona, use /opt/local/var/run/percona/mysqld.sock
```

Comment: I am using Mountain Lion and have installed MySQL using macports.

Answer (score 1):

i was having the same issue

**[PDOException]
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory**

**[ErrorException]
Warning: PDO::__construct(): [2002] No such file or directory (trying to connect via unix:///var/mysql/mysql.sock) in …htdocs/Symfony/vendor/doctrine-dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php**

So the solution is to make a symlink to the sock file thus resolving the issue. Do the following to resolve it:

*$ sudo mkdir /private/var/mysql/*

*$ sudo ln -s /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock /private/var/mysql/mysql.sock*

source:http://www.reecefowell.com/2012/07/21/symfony2-cli-does-not-connect-to-mysql-while-browser-works-fine/

Comment: Post your answer here, rather than a link to an external website.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same errors.
Mysql was running as a standalone application before I started phpMyAdmin.

I just stopped mysql
Then
sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/xampp stop
sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/xampp start

It worked fine

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem, but it only appeared when loading certain pages (other pages worked fine). It turned out that I was making calls to MySQL after I closed the connection with `mysql_close()`. So, as @brucenan said: **make sure that MySQL is running when you call it**.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by simply aliasing the MAMP php on Apple terminal:

```
alias phpmamp='/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.0/bin/php'
```

Example: `> phpmamp - v`

Now you can run something like: `> phpmamp scriptname.php`

Note: This will be applied only for the current terminal session.

Answer (score 0):

Since your might use MAMP, either change your Port to the default 3306 or use 127.0.0.1 in the database.php

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',// leave it for port 3306
    'username' => 'yourUserhere',
    'password' => 'yourPassword',
    'database' => 'yourDatabase',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Or with the default settings:

```
$db['default'] = array(
        'dsn'   => '',
        'hostname' => '127.0.0.1:8889',// leave it for port 8889
        'username' => 'yourUserhere',
        'password' => 'yourPassword',
        'database' => 'yourDatabase',
        'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
        'dbprefix' => '',
        'pconnect' => FALSE,
        'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
        'cache_on' => FALSE,
        'cachedir' => '',
        'char_set' => 'utf8',
        'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
        'swap_pre' => '',
        'encrypt' => FALSE,
        'compress' => FALSE,
        'stricton' => FALSE,
        'failover' => array(),
        'save_queries' => TRUE
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

The mySQL client by default attempts to connect through a local file called a socket instead of connecting to the loopback address (127.0.0.1) for localhost.

The default location of this socket file, at least on OSX, is `/tmp/mysql.sock`.

QUICK, LESS ELEGANT SOLUTION

Create a symlink to fool the OS into finding the correct socket.

```
ln -s /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock /tmp
```

PROPER SOLUTION

Change the socket path defined in the `startMysql.sh` file in `/Applications/MAMP/bin`.