# php cannot connect to DB when execute in terminal

Tags: php, mysql

im connecting my php script with this simple code:

> mysql_connect("localhost", "admin", "1admin") or die("DB Failed");
>   mysql_select_db("test") or die(mysql_error());

but when execute in terminal, DB failed. however this works on browser.

Comment: What error output is produced?

Comment: are you really on the same machine? print the error message on mysql_connect() es well, nut just on mysql_select_db and post it here!

Comment: hi yankee and george, the errors are : Warning: mysql_connect(): [2002] No such file or directory (trying to connect via unix:///var/mysql/mysql.sock) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project/file.php on line 24

Warning: mysql_connect(): No such file or directory in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project/file.php on line 24
No such file or directory

Comment: Please check if there is a difference in mysql.default_socket in your command-line php.ini and your webserver php.ini.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219970/warning-mysql-connect-2002-no-such-file-or-directory-trying-to-connect-via

Answer (score 3):

PHP from commandline usually uses a different php.ini from php-cli. If your are on a linux server - look into /etc/php/cli/php.ini (Or something like that...)

Check if mysql is enabled in this php.ini

Comment: im using MAMP on Mac OsX. i checked both php5.2 and php5.3, mysql is enabled

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
mysql_connect(...) or die(mysql_error());
```

Simply outputting "db failed" is useless for diagnost purposes, especially when MySQL will tell you exactly what's wrong with mysql_error().

Comment: hi the error is No such file or directory

Comment: Is there a db named 'test' in your setup? It should be there, but not necessarily.

Comment: hi my db is not test. i just change the name. but with the correct db, it still output the same error

Comment: Ah. given your comment up above, MySQL's mis-configured and is looking for the server's socket file somewhere where it is (or mysql isn't running).