# Code Igniter GroceryCRUD Tutorial Fata Exception Table DOes Not Exist

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm new to Code Igniter and GroceryCRUD. After the basic installation and verification I created the database tables and began following the newbie tutorial located here.

http://www.grocerycrud.com/documentation/create-crud-codeigniter-tutorial

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception Exception with message The table name does not exist.
Please check you database and try again. in /Library/WebServer/Documents/application/libraries/Grocery_CRUD.php:4349
Stack trace: #0 /Library/WebServer/Documents/application/libraries/Grocery_CRUD.php(3875):
grocery_CRUD->get_table() #1 /Library/WebServer/Documents/application/libraries/Grocery_CRUD.php(3891):
grocery_CRUD->pre_render() #2

/Library/WebServer/Documents/application/controllers/main.php(27): grocery_CRUD->render() #3
[internal function]: Main->employees() #4 /Library/WebServer/Documents/system/core/CodeIgniter.php(359): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #5
/Library/WebServer/Documents/index.php(202): require_once(/Library/WebSer...) #6
{main} thrown in /Library/WebServer/Documents/application/libraries/Grocery_CRUD.php on line 4349
```

I'm getting the table does not exist and when I modify the main.php to display the table list

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($this->db->list_tables());
die();
```

I get an empty array back. So I think maybe something is wrong with the MySQL user I configured, somehow the database is not getting selected although the database connection is successful (or I would bomb out earlier in the initialization process).

My Configuration

Mac OSX 10.7.5

database.php

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'cruduser';
$db['default']['password'] = 'foo45bar';
$db['default']['database'] = 'crud';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

The result of $this->db->list_tables()); in the main.php

**Welcome to the world of Codeigniter**

```
Array
(
)
```

SELECT of MySQL User table

```
mysql> select host,user  from mysql.user;
+-----------+----------+
| host      | user     |
+-----------+----------+
| %         | cruduser |
| localhost | root     |
+-----------+----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

SHOW databases in MySQL

```
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| crud               |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
+--------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

SHOW Tables in 'crud' database

```
mysql> show tables;
+----------------+
| Tables_in_crud |
+----------------+
| actor          |
| category       |
| customers      |
| employees      |
| film           |
| film_actor     |
| film_category  |
| offices        |
| orderdetails   |
| orders         |
| payments       |
| productlines   |
| products       |
+----------------+
13 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Source to main.php

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Main extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        /* Standard Libraries of codeigniter are required */
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->helper('url');
        /* ------------------ */

        $this->load->library('grocery_CRUD');

    }

    public function index()
    {
        echo "<h1>Welcome to the world of Codeigniter</h1>";//Just an example to ensure that we get into the function


echo "<pre>";
print_r($this->db->list_tables());
die();
}

    public function employees()
    {
        $this->grocery_crud->set_table('employees');
        $output = $this->grocery_crud->render();

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($output);
        echo "</pre>";
        die();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is on Stack Overflow in this message [CodeIgniter: Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings Error Message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7254049/codeigniter-unable-to-connect-to-your-database-server-using-the-provided-settin)

The problem is that on OSX the /private/etc/php.ini.default must be edited and saved as php.ini with a change to the property was pointing to /var/mysql/mysql.sock but in OSX, the file was located in /tmp/mysql.sock.

Change this

```
mysql.default_socket = /var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

to this

```
mysql.default_socket = /tmp/mysql.sock
```

and bounce apache

George