# CodeIgniter error when connecting to the database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to uplaod my web to a host, I've had some problems I managed to solve but no this one. It's related to the database, and it only happens sometimes.

In some cases I have to query the database or even for the user registration it works fine, but in other cases I got the error:

> Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.
>
> Filename: core/Loader.php
>
> Line Number: 346

I debugged the error (thanks @Valeh Hajiyev: [CodeIgniter: Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings Error Message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7254049/codeigniter-unable-to-connect-to-your-database-server-using-the-provided-settin)) and in every case the connection seemed to be fine.

I hope someone who has had this problem before could help me.

**EDIT:** Oh snap! I just found out that refreshing the page a couple of times makes it work. What??

Comment: Looks like the MySQL server is going down, You'll have to contact your host regarding this.

Comment: Yeah it sounds like a hosting problem

Comment: It's a free hosting, I am just testing. So no problem with my code right, just the hosting?

Comment: when your problem solved by refresh the page!! so this comes from your host!