# Database loading issue in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, load

I am working on a codeigniter site, sometime it shows database loading issue.It shows

```
A Database Error Occurred
Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

Filename: core/Loader.php

Line Number: 232
```

My Database connectivity

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'qwerty';
$db['default']['password'] = '123456';
$db['default']['database'] = 'codeigntr_DB';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

I am loading my database in autoload.php

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session');
```

Is it due to huge amount of data in database?How can I solve this problem?Anyone please help me

Comment: Many successful solutions are answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7254049/codeigniter-unable-to-connect-to-your-database-server-using-the-provided-settin

Answer (score 0):

try to change

```
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
```

to

```
$db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
```

and also change db driver

```
mysql
```

to

```
mysqli
```