# Connect with remote mySql from localhost with codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a remote mysql server. Now I am developing a software in Codeigniter integrated with that mysql server. I gave the GRANT ALL to 'user'@'myid' in mysql user. But codeigniter shows the following error:

```
A Database Error Occurred
Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.
```

How can i use remote mysql in my local development environment?

BTW: I use `WAMP` in `windown 7`.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Database Configuration:

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = '198.xxx.xx.66';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = 'xxxxxx';
$db['default']['database'] = 'm000db';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: Please post your db setting code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8808509/545138

Comment: on which port number your remote database is running on? @Arif

Comment: @RonakJoshi Its the default port 3306

Comment: can you connect to it with desktop tools like MySql workbench or HeidiSql?

Comment: Yes, agree with @charlietfl. Because some times MySQL could not connect with default port number. So,try to change port number on remote side and then add this line to config, `$db['default']['port'] = '3307';`

Comment: @RonakJoshi is there any way with changing default port?