# Codeigniter - Cannot Remote Database Server

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I really got confused of how to remote my server database from codeigniter project on local server. It is look like i have setup everything correctly.

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'xxx.xx.xxx.xx';
$db['default']['username'] = 'username';
$db['default']['password'] = 'password';
$db['default']['database'] = 'db';
```

But from that code i always get the same error on the browser,

```
Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

Filename: core/Loader.php
```

I have setup the configuration in **database.php**.

Can someone please help me with this problem?
I really need to remote it from local

Comment: Your DB server may be configured not to allow any connections except from `localhost`, see if you need to add your IP to its access list.

Comment: I see, i have setup an access host with my computer ip xx.xx.xxx.xx, but i still cant access my database server. Do you have another sugestion? @DeDee

Comment: try setting `$db['default']['pconnect'] = true;`

Comment: There are many potential solutions to your problem at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7254049/codeigniter-unable-to-connect-to-your-database-server-using-the-provided-settin