# Ubuntu 14.04 Codeigniter ODBC Connection to Sybase SQL Anywhere 9

Tags: php, codeigniter, sybase, unixodbc

I create an application with CodeIgniter2.3 Framework and it need to connect to Sybase SQL Anywhere 9 on **Windows Server**. I have already create ODBC in the Windows Server so the web application can use it.

When the I put the web application on **Apache server located on Windows**, it **successfully** connect to Sybase using PDO_ODBC. But the CI shows error that it cannot connect to Sybase using my database configuration when I try to put the application on **Apache server located on Ubuntu14.04**.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Are your parameters in `database.php` correct?

Comment: i tried using the same parameters and run the application on apache installed on windows and it works perfectly. The problem occurs when I run the application on Ubuntu

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting?? add that as well.

Comment: I got this error message `Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings. Filename: core/Loader.php Line Number: 339`

Comment: This error means database parameters are wrong. Check again dude.

Comment: check this link once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7254049/codeigniter-unable-to-connect-to-your-database-server-using-the-provided-settin

Comment: Thanks for your response. I use the same configuration file in windows. It works.