# Codeigniter error when trying to connect to database using mysqli

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am getting Following error in my CodeIgniter application which is live on server.

Here is the output of the error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/1044): Access denied for user
>   'xxx'@'localhost' to database 'xxx'
>
> Filename: mysqli/mysqli_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 161
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: /home/arya123/public_html/application/controllers/Home.php Line:
>   7 Function: __construct
>
> File: /home/arya123/public_html/index.php Line: 292 Function:
>   require_once

Comment: In database file which extension r u using? `$config['dbdriver'] = "mysqli";`

Comment: Seems like you don't have persmission to approach to that DB. Is it external DB or `localhost` (server's) one?

Comment: Have you checked that the application/config/database.php settings are correct?

Comment: if you are using shared hosting su as godaddy, I suggest you check the user which you created, because I had same problem, but It was the problem of user's permission in mysql

Comment: if you using OSX, this is the correct answer for you [CodeIgniter: Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings Error Message](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11043416/5531595)

Comment: Make sure user `xxx` actually has the privileges to connect to database `xxx`

Comment: try localhost:3306.. i have mysqlworkbench(localhost:3306) and phpmyadmin (localhost)

Answer (score 6):

you have to set mysql port number which is by default 3306 [check this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connecting.html) in database.php

use either

```
'dbport' => '3306',
```

or

```
 'hostname' => 'mysql.hostingprovider.com:3306',
```

Answer (score 4):

Connect localhost with port solves the problem for me.

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn' => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost:3308', //Added port here
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '1234',
    'database' => 'my_database',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Answer (score 1):

The same error I was getting when I upload my codeigniter project from localhost to Live server.

What solution I find is to make some changes into the application => config => database.php

Following is the database setting for the

> localhost

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'creator',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Following database setting for

> live server (Just demo, setting differ as per hosting provider)

1) First you have to create database.

2) find MySql Databases(or anything related database) on dashboard,

3) create new database and put database name, username, password.

4) export database from localhost

5) open phpmyadmin on live server and import it.

6) change the setting of application=>config=>database.php by using FTP client or dashboard.

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'mysql.hostingprovider.com',    
    'username' => 'abc.username',
    'password' => 'abc.password',
    'database' => 'abc.databasename',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Comment: Have you find any difficulty to following this steps? or you miss something? have you change hostname, username, password, dbname? please recheck it!

Comment: Yes Everything as you mentioned

Answer (score 1):

u can add new user and pass and give it all privileges, like below:

```
CREATE USER 'newuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'newuser'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

then, u should update your config.php file, with new user and pass.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

1. In `applications/config/database.php`, add `dbport => '3306',` to the default array `$db['default'] = array();`
2. In `system/database/DB_driver.php`, change `public $port = '';` to `public $port = '3306';`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the plain password with no special characters, below is the example:

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'password',
    'password' => 'Mynewpass@756',
    'database' => 'database_name',
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your server's php.ini file to define the port that CodeIgniter will use by default.

`C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.41\bin\php.ini`

Default port number for `mysqli_connect()`.

`mysqli.default_port = 3308`

Answer (score 0):

Try to set config/database.php 'username' => 'xxx' to 'username' => 'root' without any password.

```
$db['default'] = array( 
'dsn' => '',
'hostname' => 'localhost',
'username' => 'root',
'password' => '',
```

Answer (score 0):

verify is user has the rights privilege declare on database

Answer (score 0):

i was having the same issue in CodeIgniter code. database and everything was correct but i fixed it by changing these lines

**Before**

```
    'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=kiuurduapp',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'kiuurdu',
```

**After**

```
    'dsn' => 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=kiuurduapp',
    'hostname' => '',
    'username' => 'kiuurdu',
```

and it works for me

Answer (score -1):

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'xxx',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same trouble.
Since I use xampp and I was running my codeigniter app locally, the problem at the end I solved it by remplacing:
'hostname' => 'localhost ' 
 by
'hostname' => '127.0.0.1:33065' 
 the :33065 is the port assigned by default by xampp for phpmyadmin. 
If you are running your proyect in the xampp default options, changing this, should be enough (hopefully).
But if you don´t, I guess, you can search which port you are using for the database conection, and add it to your hostname with ":" (if you are not sure which port you are using, you always can see in your D.B. administration tool -phpmyadmin or the one you are using- on the options, which port is taking).