# "Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings."

Tags: php, postgresql, codeigniter, heroku

how to import mysqldb into heroku postgres?
I am getting an error  In *codeigniter*

these are my settings:

```
$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;


'hostname' => 'localhost',
'username' => 'root',
'password' => '',
'database' => 'whatsapp',
'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
'dbprefix' => '',
```

Answer (score 0):

You should post the error you are getting, this way others can maybe help you.

I found also this solution that, may or may not be helpful:

> For me the issue was in the php.ini file. The property mysql.default_socket was pointing to file in a non-existent directory. The property was pointing to /var/mysql/mysql.sock but in OSX, the file was located in /tmp/mysql.sock.

[Source: CodeIgniter: Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings Error Message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7254049/codeigniter-unable-to-connect-to-your-database-server-using-the-provided-settin?rq=1)

Comment: this is the error 

Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [mysql-postgresql-converter](https://github.com/lanyrd/mysql-postgresql-converter) Dump MySQL database in PostgreSQL-compatible format

```
mysqldump -u username -p --compatible=postgresql databasename > database.sql
```

then use the converter to transfer data into *.psql file. then load new dump into a fresh PostgreSQL database