# MySQL database issue in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am facing some occasional database related issues for my app, where more than half a million users are registered, a few thousand of requests coming every minute to the server
the app performs very well and server response time is good but every day for some time the database related errors start popping, I have attached a few screenshots of different kind of errors
The database is MySQL(v5.7) and the backend is running on Codeigniter3 (PHP v5.6) 
I believe it happens during the peak usage period mostly in the evening

Showing the connectivity error which comes quite often when the problem starts happening]:
[image]

The error says

```
Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings
Filename: third_party/MX/Base.php
Line Number: 55
```

The above error may look like the configuration settings are incorrect but the application runs fine with the same settings

This is another error which appears sometimes:
[image]

```
Error Number: 9001
Max connect timeout while reaching hostgroup 11 after 11043ms
SELECT * FROM `uc_role_rights` WHERE `user_role_id` = '1' AND `module_id` = 18 AND `module_view` = 1
Filename: modules/settings/models/Settings_model.php
Line Number: 100
```

Few more information which may help you to understand it

> 1. max_connections is set to 151
> 2. In Codeigniter's database connection configuration `pconnect` is set to FALSE
> 3. Used `dbdriver` is `mysqli`
> 4. Database hosted on 'localhost'

I'd appreciate any help to reach to the root of the problem.
Thanx

Comment: Please add the error message in readable form to your question. Text can be shared best as text, not as an image

Comment: Thanx Nico, I have added the error text in the question's body

Comment: [You can check this reference link to get idea about, for solving your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7254049/codeigniter-unable-to-connect-to-your-database-server-using-the-provided-settin)

Comment: This is not a programming problem. Suggest taking it to [sf] or https://dba.stackexchange.com