# CodeIgniter 3 :- Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, xampp

The Above errors occur when I update my windows to window 11
Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/elitenelegant/system/database/DB_driver.php
The following message occurs when I open my project on localhost
Message: mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

Filename: mysqli/mysqli_driver.php

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CodeIgniter: Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings Error Message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7254049/codeigniter-unable-to-connect-to-your-database-server-using-the-provided-settin)

Answer (score 0):

the error is in your database.php

You must verify the params of connection like hostname, password, dns
and refresh page.

This worked for me.