# Codeigniter Error "Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings"

Tags: php, codeigniter

When I trying upload this project on my domain m facing error "Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings"

I have checked my **config.php** and **database.php** file and all the information are correct:

```
 $db['default']['hostname'] = "etc.com";
 $db['default']['username'] = "etc"; 
 $db['default']['password'] = "etc@etc";
 $db['default']['database'] = "visiting_link";
 $db['default']['dbdriver'] = "mysql";
 $db['default']['dbprefix'] = "";
 $db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
 $db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
 $db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
 $db['default']['cachedir'] = "";
 $db['default']['char_set'] = "utf8";
 $db['default']['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";
```

Is any solution to that problem? please refer any helping material.
I am using fileZilla. 
Thanks !

Comment: Try changing the `hostname` parameter to the IP address associated with the domain.

Answer (score 14):

Setting "db_debug" to false solved my problem.

I'm using Snow Leopard.

EDIT: db_debug just obfuscated my direction. The solution in my case was just the mysql.sock reference path, as solved on this question: [Warning: mysql_connect(): [2002] No such file or directory (trying to connect via unix:///tmp/mysql.sock) in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219970/warning-mysql-connect-2002-no-such-file-or-directory-trying-to-connect-vi)

OS X use /tmp/mysql.sock, and by default php.ini is referencing /var/mysql/mysql.sock. Just creating a symlink solves the problem:

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/mysql/ && cd /var/mysql/
sudo ln -s /tmp/mysql.sock ./mysql.sock
```

Answer (score 3):

Try setting the 'dbdriver' to 'mysqli'

```
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = "mysqli";
```

It's the MySQL Improved Extension (http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) and your server may be set to use this rather than the standard MySQL extension.

I've seen this happen a few times when all other settings are correct, as the connection will fail if the wrong driver is selected.

Answer (score 3):

I was getting this error

```
    <div id="container">
        <h1>A Database Error Occurred</h1>
        <p>Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.</p>
        <p>Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/WORK/Vishal/UI-Demo/system/database/DB_driver.php</p>
        <p>Line Number: 436</p>
    </div>
```

I resolved this error by change debug option to FALSE in database.php

**'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),**

TO

**'db_debug' => FALSE,**

Change this

```
$db['default'] = array(
'dsn'   => '',
'hostname' => 'XXXX',
'username' => 'XXXX',
'password' => 'XXXX',
'database' => 'XXX',
'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
'dbprefix' => '',
'pconnect' => FALSE,
'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
'cache_on' => FALSE,
'cachedir' => '',
'char_set' => 'utf8',
'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
'swap_pre' => '',
'encrypt' => FALSE,
'compress' => FALSE,
'stricton' => FALSE,
'failover' => array(),
'save_queries' => TRUE
```

);

**To**

```
$db['default'] = array(
'dsn'   => '',
'hostname' => 'XXXX',
'username' => 'XXXX',
'password' => 'XXXX',
'database' => 'XXX',
'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
'dbprefix' => '',
'pconnect' => FALSE,
'db_debug' => FALSE,
'cache_on' => FALSE,
'cachedir' => '',
'char_set' => 'utf8',
'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
'swap_pre' => '',
'encrypt' => FALSE,
'compress' => FALSE,
'stricton' => FALSE,
'failover' => array(),
'save_queries' => TRUE
```

);

Answer (score 2):

If the database settings are correct, than something is wrong anywhere else:

- maybe the database does not accept connections from anywhere; in this case, you need to allow connections from your 'username'@'server IP'
- maybe PHP or the server itself is not allowing the connection, due to a php.ini setting, a firewall, or something else

Back to the CI DB settings, you need to be sure they are correct. Are you sure the "hostname" is correct?

Answer (score 1):

If you are facing this issue in shared hosting environment. Then i think you have to give the database credentials same as cpanel/hosting credentials.

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = "localhost";
$db['default']['username'] = "cpanel/hosting username"; 
$db['default']['password'] = "cpanel/hosting password";
$db['default']['database'] = "dbname";
```

Answer (score 1):

if u use codeigniter 3 then please use latest version of php. Once i got these errors but then i update my php then it works after successfully setup codeigniter on my project.

And please follow in your application/config/database.php

```
$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'db_bdtimes', // your database name
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this $db['default']['hostname'] = "localhost";

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem while deploying a codeigniter CMS on server, although it was working fine in localhost with TRUE attribute.
change this line in database.php to look like this :

```
$db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
```

Also CHECK if this line matches the collation of your server's database(for all tables as well):

```
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";
```