# Run controllers via command-line. Issue connecting to the database

Tags: database, codeigniter, database-connection, command-line-interface

Background: Using unix, codeigniter from localhost.

I'd like to run a controllers via a command-line (CLI).
Consequently I'm following [this CodeIgniter tutorial](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/cli.html)  and the example works fine.

**However** when I use it with functions which need to connect to the database, then it appears the following error in the command-line.

```
Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.
Filename: core/Loader.php
Line Number: 347
```

**The strange thing** is when I access to the same function via URL it works.
How that's possible?

Note: The function I pretend to introduce in the command-line is to update the database (it doesn't print anything).

**EDIT:**
I'm getting closer.
I've changed the hostname from 'localhost' to '127.0.0.1' and it works. Why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've changed the hostname from 'localhost' to '127.0.0.1' and it works.

[Explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219970/warning-mysql-connect-2002-no-such-file-or-directory-trying-to-connect-vi)