# Running php script that connects to mysql db in shell

Tags: php, mysql, shell

I prefer running php scripts in the shell as the output comes directly and not in tranches like in a browser. This can be very helpful to see the script is actually still working and also to see which part of a long script takes the longest.

When I call php scripts from the shell like this

```
php filename.php
```

it works fine, but only so long as no db connection is established in the script.

Apparently, the mysql_connect() seems to fail:

```
Warning: mysql_connect(): [2002] No such file or directory (trying to connect via unix:///var/mysql/mysql.sock)
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Charles

EDIT 1

I connect to the db as follows:

```
//Connect to db
$user="root";
$databasePassword="";
$host="localhost";
$database="database1";
$identifier=mysql_connect($host,$user,$databasePassword,true);
$db1=mysql_select_db($database);
```

**SOLUTION FOUND**

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219970/warning-mysql-connect-2002-no-such-file-or-directory-trying-to-connect-vi) showed me the right way to do it - it's as simple as replacing "localhost" with "127.0.0.1", because: "The reason is that "localhost" is a special name for the mysql driver making it use the unix socket to connect to mysql instead of the a tcp socket."

Comment: Does the mysql unix socket exist at `/var/mysql/mysql.sock`?

Comment: What OS? You might have to change the path of mysql, check the path

Comment: As stated in [the introduction to the PHP manual chapter on the `mysql_*` functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php): *This extension is not recommended for writing new code. Instead, either the [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also the [MySQL API Overview](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.*

Comment: Kush I run Mac OS X 10.7.4.
@JonLin How do I check whether the socket exists there?

Comment: you COULD have permission issues...

Comment: Solution found. Please see question edit. Thank you very much nonetheless!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show your mysql_connect() statement, perhaps you should try to connect to localhost:3306 if your daemon listens on this port.

see: php.net/mysql_connect

If the same script works when called via browser obviously your ini files for the command line environment differ. ini_get("mysql.default_host") shows what setting is used if you do not specify a host to connect to.

Comment: ini_get("mysql.default_host") does not show anything...
localhost:3306 instead of localhost does not work (although it runs on 3306)

Comment: Please see question edit - this is how I connect. In the browser everything works fine.