# Mysql connection refused on localhost

Tags: php, mysql, macos

After an upgrade to El Capitan I'm having issues connecting to MySql. I have a basic PHP file called `index.php` with the following code:

```
<?php
  $conn = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "xxxx", "xxxx");
  if ($conn->connect_error) die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error); 
  echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

Now when I visit the page in my browser, I get the following message:

```
Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in /Users/rich/Documents/DESIGN/test/index.php on line 3
Connection failed: Connection refused
```

I can't understand what's going wrong here. I should mention that I also had this problem on Yosemite before upgrade. The problem began when I wiped my computer to do a fresh install and had to setup Apache and PHP config again. I think something must have been left out of one of the files.

**EDIT**
I've also tried using `localhost` in the connection instead of `127.0.0.1`. That changes the error slightly to:

```
Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory in /Users/rich/Documents/DESIGN/test/index.php on line 4
Connection failed: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Can you set the port?

Comment: What should the port be?

Comment: possible duplicate of other questions around "no such file": [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12584762/mysql-connect-no-such-file-or-directory)  or [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219970/warning-mysql-connect-2002-no-such-file-or-directory-trying-to-connect-vi)...

Answer (score 2):

Try using localhost instead of 127.0.0.1 and also make sure the username/password you are using are correct and exist on the mysql server. Also check mysqld is running and that your firewall is allowing the mysql database through.

Edit your php.ini file and make sure extension extension=php_mysqli.dll is enabled on Windows or extension=php_mysqli.so on Linux.

Try the answer here: [PHP - MYSQL - test database server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13870362/php-mysql-test-database-server)

There are two settings you have to check for this to work (assuming you have MySQL server installed of course):

Check the value of mysql.default_socket in your PHP configuration.

Check the value of socket in your MySQL configuration file under the [mysqld] heading.

Those values have to be identical; if they're not, change one to match the other and restart respective service.

Comment: Using `localhost` instead changes the error slightly to: `Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory`. I have my firewall turned off so it can't be that. Username and password are correct because I can connect through sequel pro still for some reason.

Comment: I've enabled `extension=php_mysql.dll` (by the way I'm on Mac not Windows or Linux). This still hasn't worked.

Comment: Yes but you need to enable mysqli for the mysqli functionality. With mysql you can only use mysql_calls

Comment: Is there a reason why someone has given me negative on this answer? these are all things to check when geting these types of errors. You do need mysqli to use mysqli calls.

Comment: Not sure why someone downvoted my question either... As far as I can tell I have all mysqli things enabled but this still isn't working. Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: By the way I only have a `php.ini.default` file, should I remain this to `php.ini`?

Comment: YES :) That may be the issue!

Comment: And restart services so the config is loaded.

Comment: Slight progress made there. I now only get a simply error: `Connection failed: Connection refused`

Comment: Sounds like mysql service is not running. Try starting it or restarting it.

Comment: I think it might be something to do with connecting to the socket but not sure.

Comment: I've restarted MySql and apache

Comment: No fraid not. I'm in my file `usr/local/mysql/support-files/my-default.cnf` and everything is commented out by default. I've uncommented the `socket` line and changed it to `socket=/var/mysql/mysql.sock`

Comment: Then in `php.ini` I've set: `pdo_mysql.default_socket=/var/mysql/mysql.sock` so they match. Same error still shows after restarting apache.

Comment: You must have a my.cnf file for mysql config. not my-default.cnf, this wont be loaded!

Comment: OK I've duplicated that file and called it `my.conf` (why don't these files exist by default?!?!) Now I've discovered that /var/mysql/mysql.sock doesn't exist. What do I do now?

Comment: When you restart your services, these sock files are created automatically. They come like this so you can configure them to your liking.

Comment: See if this helps @Coop http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784791/cant-connect-to-mysql-on-mac-missing-mysql-sock-file

Comment: I ended up taking drastic measures and wiping my computer for a fresh El Capitan install for this reason and many others. That solved this problem but I'm now having mysql password issues. Thanks for your help though.