# shell_exec a php file with mysql inside not working

Tags: php, mysql, background, exec, shell-exec

I have a simple `shell_exec()` script in my php script. On upload this line is run:

```
shell_exec("php  process.php > /dev/null &");
```

It definitely runs the file happily in the background as intended, but it seems to have trouble connecting to mysql in process.php

process.php includes:

```
$db_host="localhost";
$db_name="databasename";
$dbusername="root";
$dbpassword="pass";

mysql_connect($db_host,$dbusername,$dbpassword);
mysql_select_db($db_name);
//then a mysql_query()
```

It seems that `mysql_connect()` fails. If I copy and paste all of this into the first file in place of my `shell_exec()` it works fine.

Is there something about 'localhost' as the mysql host when running `shell_exec()`? I am testing in xampp on mac btw

Comment: Try with `127.0.0.1`...

Comment: How do you know it fails? Does it give an error message (please add it to your question)

Comment: Try piping the output of your script into a regular file instead of `/dev/null` and look for error messages.

Comment: You should check the arguments for [php](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php), try to load the php.ini and maybe the mysql extention?

Comment: and also use die function in mysql_connect, mysql_select_db and mysql_query to know where it failed

Comment: @Ikke - I know it fails there because I had a line to create a file and tested it by moving the line through the script on each try and the only time it stopped creating it was when it went after mysql_connect (which I also added 'or die' to

Comment: The script that does not fail runs through a web browser, doesn't it?

Comment: @user32571 Make it `or die(mysql_error());`. That way it will give you an error message;

Comment: @Mihai - 127.0.0.1 worked instead of localhost. Any reason why this would be?

Comment: what is the result of mysql_error? in case you use "localhost". maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219970/warning-mysql-connect-2002-no-such-file-or-directory-trying-to-connect-vi) is the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use full path to PHP binary `/usr/local/bin/php` instead of `php`
- Make sure that `process.php` file is executable
- You could use ip's instead of hostnames (*i.e: 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost*) to slightly speed up things.
- Remove the /dev/null part so you can see errors and warnings.

Comment: The speed up of using ip's instead of names is minimal (especially things like localhost, because it doesn't have to hit the network).

Comment: using 127.0.0.1 worked. Thanks! Why would that be? And what would I set it to when I upload to my live hosting server?!?

Comment: @Ikke I agree with you, but connection to mysql on some LAMP stacks can not be made using `localhost`.