# PHPUnit and mysqli_connect generate warning

Tags: php, mysql, unit-testing, phpunit

I'm new to unit testing and want to start using for a large project I'm working on. I've got PHPUnit running on my Mac (10.8.3) alongside MAMP. The application I'm writing unit tests for relies heavily on the database.

In one of the classes I'm testing, it creates a connection to a MySQL database using `mysqli_connect` - however it is failing with this error:

`Warning: mysqli_connect(): [2002] No such file or directory (trying to connect via unix:///var/mysql/mysql.sock) in /[PATH TO FILE]/database.php on line 340`

I am I unable to connect to a database when running unit tests, or is there something extra I need to setup? The database is also running locally on my machine.

Comment: Unit tests should not connect to a database

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution of your problem(Hope so).

Check the following link:

[Warning: mysql_connect(): [2002] No such file or directory (trying to connect via unix:///tmp/mysql.sock) in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219970/warning-mysql-connect-2002-no-such-file-or-directory-trying-to-connect-vi)

[mysql_connect-no-such-file](http://blog.mpdaugherty.com/2010/06/02/mysql_connect-no-such-file/).

This error occurs due to the setting in php.ini file. you need to alter that file.

Hope this will provide you some solution.

Comment: Thanks - the link didn't solve the problem, but pointed me in the right direction (see my answer).

Comment: @gbuckingham89 I am not expert in mysqli that's why i can only show the way.

Answer (score 1):

Turned out to be an issue with PHPUnit look for a MySQL socket in the wrong location - the one set in `php.ini` was correct.

Following the last command from this tutorial solved the issue: http://tommcfarlin.com/phpunit-wordpress-mamp/

Comment: To clarify, this article refers to using MAMP for MySQL. To resolve the issue, create a symlink using these commands: 
`sudo mkdir /var/mysql` and then `sudo ln -s /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock /var/mysql/mysql.sock`