# codeigniter - cannot connect to MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

**Error that is getting printed out**

```
Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

Filename: core/Loader.php

Line Number: 346
```

I have been looking through all the other questions and nothing seems to work. Still getting this error. All the info in my `database.php` file matched up to my info on the mysql server that I am running on the command line. I am also using `mysqld` and `mysql.server start`. I have tested the connection on the command line with

`mysql -h localhost -uroot -p dbname`

And that seems to work on my command line, but it is giving me the error above when I am referencing it on a localhost server I have set up with the codeigniter project. What am i doing wrong? I have double and triple checked naming conventions to make sure that it isn't the issue.

Also, I am on OS X Mavericks

my code in the config file is as follows:

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = 'PASS';
$db['default']['database'] = 'dbname';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: Your database credentials are likely wrong. What code are you using to connect to it?

Comment: When connecting to the mysql server, are you specifying the IP or the Hostname as the database server host? What version of CI are you using? Can you show your config file obfuscating the password?

Comment: Have you checked the php error log, and the mysql connection log?

Comment: updated with error log

Comment: Could be as simple as PHP or CI not looking for the mysql socket in the right place.

Comment: @JustinE where would I find the PHP error or mysql connection logs?

Comment: in your config file set your database as `DBNAME` but in your command you write it `dbname` they are not the same

Comment: @MajidGolshadi...that is just a place holder, i apologize for the confusion

Comment: Using LAMP or something? Pull up phpmyadmin to double check the settings

Comment: Try with `$db['default']['db_debug'] = FALSE;` please

Comment: tryed 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost ?

Answer (score 5):

I have run into this problem frequently myself with CodeIgniter.  The usual solution (for me!) is to set 'pconnect' and 'db_debug' to FALSE:

```
$db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
```

Answer (score 3):

I tried to change the following line in my config/database.php file and it worked. (The error your getting means something is wrong with your config/database.php)

```
'hostname' => '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock',
```

Explanation for this behaviour is written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219970/warning-mysql-connect-2002-no-such-file-or-directory-trying-to-connect-vi) (MySQL on OSX finds mysql.sock wrongly).

Cheers!