# fail to connect to local mysql from php

Tags: php, mysql, mamp

I am developing on mac using MAMP
I try to connect to my local mysql database from php:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","testDB");
```

this is the error I get:

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory in
>   /Users/tshahar/Documents/Dev/server/test.php on line 20 Failed to
>   connect to MySQL: No such file or directory

Comment: I've never worked in MAMP before but shouldn't you execute a PHP file from within your web server (MAMP)'s directory instead of your Documents folder? 
If MAMP gives you that ability then check the path and see if the file `test.php` actually exists on that path.

Comment: Post all your,code , the error you get doesn't link to the code you post

Comment: that is the only line of code in my php file

Answer (score 1):

To summarize, use:

> *127.0.0.1*

Instead of:

> *localhost*

The reason is that "localhost" is a special name for the mysql driver making it use the unix socket to connect to mysql instead of the a tcp socket.

refer this link:

[***click here to example***](http://webdevjourney.wordpress.com/2011/04/20/warning-mysql_connect-function-mysql-connect-no-such-file-or-directory/)

***source from:1***

***[Warning: mysql_connect(): [2002] No such file or directory (trying to connect via unix:///tmp/mysql.sock) in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219970/warning-mysql-connect-2002-no-such-file-or-directory-trying-to-connect-vi)***

Answer (score 0):

Try using IP instead for local host that would be 127.0.0.1 or ::1 if your system does IPV6.

can't really tell you why that is but I guess the SQL won't answer to a domain name because it's configured that way.(had the same problem yesterday)

Comment: when I try IP (127.0.0.1) I get this error:  Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in /Users/tshahar/Documents/Dev/server/test.php on line 20
Failed to connect to MySQL: Connection refused[tshahar1-mac:~/Documents/Dev/server] tshahar%