# mysql connection refused and mysql no such file or directory

Tags: php, mysql, sockets, connection

Simply connecting to mysql server, username password and host all are correct.

Still mysql_error() throws the following error:

```
Warning: mysql_connect(): No such file or directory in 
save.php on line 6
No such file or directory
```

When I change it from 'localhost' to '127.0.0.1', it gives error:

```
Warning: mysql_connect(): Connection refused in 
save.php on line 6
Connection refused
```

The same connection is working without any issue for a wordpress website on the same host.

When I enter wrong password, mysql throws error of password not exist

What does it mean ?

[Update]

I checked my phpinfo() and

```
mysql.default_socket    no value    no value
```

same for default_host, user, password etc.

I tried

```
ini_set("mysql.default_socket","/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock");
```

as mention in php.ini but no luck.

Again its working for a wordpress previous install and its wp_config has the same mysql access. For wrong password sometime it throws "password not exist"

Comment: What is there on line 6?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: mysql\_connect(): \[2002\] No such file or directory (trying to connect via unix:///tmp/mysql.sock) in](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219970/warning-mysql-connect-2002-no-such-file-or-directory-trying-to-connect-vi)

Comment: @HüseyinBABAL is mysql_connect('','','')

Comment: Have you searched SO for this? There are lots of question about your case as @Rikesh stated

Comment: Yes I do, thats why I changed my localhost to 127.0.0.1, and it threw a new error. Just now I have tried ini_set('mysql.default_socket','/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock')

Answer (score 0):

Even i had faced similar problem. Please try this, hope it may works for you. Use **mysqli** instead of **mysql**

```
// Create connection

$domain   = "localhost";  // or yourdomainname.com
$username = "root";       // db username
$password = "pass123";    // db password
$dbName   = "gymchalo";   // db name

$con = mysqli_connect($domain,$username,$password,$dbName);

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){

    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    die('Mysql connection error');
}else{
    echo "Connection Established";
}
```

Comment: Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) in save.php on line 5
Failed to connect to MySQL: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)Mysql connection error