# mysql_connect( ) function not having the right username-password

Tags: mysql, database

I'm new to PHP and MySQL and I'm having a problem with MySQL database, on how to create that username-password combination for the mysql_connect() function on a Mac 10.10. Have a look at this excerpt of code from WROX book: Beginning PHP5, Apache and MySQL web development. Please help me, thanks in advance.

```
<?php

$connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "b5pm", "bm5pm") or die ("Hey loser, check your server connection.");

$create = mysql_query("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS moviesite") or die(mysql_error());

mysql_select_db("moviesite"); ... ?>
```

Comment: Is that the username and password for when you set up your database?

Comment: Yes it is! Can you help me with this? @Harry

Comment: Can you show the error message you are getting? Also are you using xampp?

Comment: No i'm not using XAMPP, here it is:

Warning: mysql_connect(): No such file or directory in /Library/WebServer/Documents/doc/createmovie.php on line 4
Hey loser, check your server connection.

Comment: Have you verified the mysql server is running?

Comment: It seems your mac is looking in the wrong place try this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219970/warning-mysql-connect-2002-no-such-file-or-directory-trying-to-connect-vi

Comment: my server is running sure

Comment: Try to change the "localhost" to "127.0.0.1"

Comment: It works now after changing that localhost, thanks Harry!

Comment: I will post this as an answer, please accept.

Comment: Yeah you can go a head!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your mac is using a UNIX socket, please change from `"localhost"` to `"127.0.0.1"`