# mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused on Live

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I create a web site using PHP, Mysql, and Codeignater version 3. Then host it on iPage. When I upload on live I make changes in config file.

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => '66.96.147.118',
    'username' => 'bit_root',
    'password' => 'root',
    'database' => 'bit_shilp',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

I use codeignater version 3. On local it work great. But on live site It gives an error.

Please see this link http://bitshilp.com/BitShilp/index.php/home

It gives an error like this:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused
>
> Filename: mysqli/mysqli_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 161
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: /hermes/bosnaweb13a/b2582/ipg.bitshilpcom/BitShilp/application/controllers/Home.php
>   Line: 7
>   Function: __construct
>
> File: /hermes/bosnaweb13a/b2582/ipg.bitshilpcom/BitShilp/index.php
>   Line: 292
>   Function: require_once
>   A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at
>   /hermes/bosnaweb13a/b2582/ipg.bitshilpcom/BitShilp/system/core/Exceptions.php:272)
>
> Filename: core/Common.php
>
> Line Number: 568
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: /hermes/bosnaweb13a/b2582/ipg.bitshilpcom/BitShilp/application/controllers/Home.php
>   Line: 7
>   Function: __construct
>
> File: /hermes/bosnaweb13a/b2582/ipg.bitshilpcom/BitShilp/index.php
>   Line: 292
>   Function: require_once

Thanks.

Comment: Does bit_root privileges look like `'bit_root'@'%'` ?

Comment: is parameters correct??

Comment: I hope for your own sake that your DB server at `66.96.147.118` (I assume you pasted the real address? You should never do that again for security reasons) does not accept MySQL connections on that external address. In most cases you need to connect to localhost or some other local address for the DB once your code is on the server.

Answer (score 2):

If MySQL Server is up and running - then this looks like some transport (e.g. firewall)  problem. First step is to try telnet command below - if it shows an error, then problem is not related to PHP or MySQL :

```
telnet 66.96.147.118 3306
```

(On success it will print mysql version + some random characters)

Answer (score 0):

Same problem occurd with me, with AWS RDS MySQL. Looked various sources, but as of this thread, almost all lack of answer.
While [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34423710) helped me, tweak in mind to update hostnames at server. Access your SSH and follow the steps:

```
cd /etc/
sudo nano hosts
```

**Now, Appending here your hostnames:** For example:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 subdomain.domain.com [if cname redirected to endpoints]
127.0.0.1 xxxxxxxx.xxxx.xxxxx.rds.amazonaws.com [Endpoints]
```

and now, configuring `config/database.php` as follows:

```
$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => '35.150.12.345',
    'username' => 'user-name-here',
    'password' => 'password-here',
    'database' => 'database-name-here',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => TRUE,
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

where `35.150.12.345` is your *IPv4 Public IP*, located at `ec2-dashboard > Network Interfaces > Description : RDSNetworkInterface >> IPv4 Public` IP('35.150.12.345') there.

**Note: Please note that only IPV4 will work at 'hostname' option. hostname, cname, domains will output database connection error.**

Answer (score 0):

You can check if mysql is running with:

```sh
mysql.server status
```

If its not then to start:

```sh
mysql.server start
```

Likewise to stop:

```sh
mysql.server stop
```

Answer (score 0):

in Codeigniter change your 'hostname' => '35.150.12.345', to 'hostname' => 'localhost',

Answer (score 0):

If this is a problem in the Fedora
You have to start MariaDB every time
just run

```
sudo systemctl start mariadb
```

Also keep in mind that every time you start, you have to start the Apache in the same way
So run the following code each time before using the above code

```
sudo service httpd start
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using Pop!_OS. After the recent OS upgrade to 21.4, it seems like MySQL packages got removed/missing automatically. Though `mysql --version` was showing that I have the MySQL available.

I've tried all other possible solutions, none of them worked. After installing MySQL again solved the issue for me. I've run the below command. Btw, *I didn't lose any database.*

```
 sudo apt-get install mariadb-server mariadb-client
```

Answer (score 0):

Please start Your xampp server, if your MYSQL Not start then it will show this type of error.

*A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
Filename: mysqli/mysqli_driver.php
Line Number: 203*

Answer (score 0):

According to the noonex's answer, I checked out my firewall with  `sudo ufw status verbose` and it threw `status: inactive` so I executed `sudo ufw enable`, then it worked.