# Codeigniter Error Message on Live server : mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am creating a website using Codeigniter(version:3.05),php(version: 5.6.24), mysql(version: 10.1.16 mariaDB). At local server: operating system=OSX, php version=5.6.24, mysql version=10.1.16 mariaDB. At Hosting server: operating system=FreeBSD(unix), phpversion= 5.6.30, mysql version=:5.5.38-log. The site works fine on local server. But it gives error on live server as shown below.

```
    A PHP Error was encountered

    Severity: Warning

    Message: mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused

    Filename: mysqli/mysqli_driver.php

    Line Number: 202

    Backtrace:

    File: /home/sv-001/www/user/myweb/application/third_party/MX/Loader.php
    Line: 109
    Function: DB

    File: /home/sv-001/www/user/myweb/application/third_party/MX/Loader.php
    Line: 65
    Function: initialize

    File: /home/sv-001/www/user/myweb/application/modules/home/controllers/Home.php
    Line: 8
    Function: __construct

    File: /home/sv-001/www/user/myweb/index.php
    Line: 294
    Function: require_once
```

I have been checking my database file(database.php) several time, but I didn't find any error there regarding hostname,username,password, database name.

database.php file

```
$db['default'] = array(
        'dsn'   => '',
        'hostname' => 'testurl.com',
        'username' => 'username',
        'password' => 'password',
        'database' => 'dbname',
        'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
        'dbprefix' => '',
        'pconnect' => FALSE,
        'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
        'cache_on' => FALSE,
        'cachedir' => '',
        'char_set' => 'utf8',
        'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
        'swap_pre' => '',
        'encrypt' => FALSE,
        'compress' => FALSE,
        'stricton' => FALSE,
        'failover' => array(),
        'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

config.php file is as shown below:

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == "localhost" OR $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == "testurl.com")
    $config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/myfolder/myfolder2/';
else if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == "testurl.com" OR $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == "testurl.com")
    $config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/myfolder2/';
else
    $config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
//$config['index_page'] = '';

$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';

$config['url_suffix'] = '';

$config['language'] = 'english';

$config['charset'] = 'UTF-8';

$config['enable_hooks'] = FALSE;

$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_';
$config['composer_autoload'] = FALSE;


$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';

$config['allow_get_array'] = TRUE;
$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
$config['controller_trigger'] = 'c';
$config['function_trigger'] = 'm';
$config['directory_trigger'] = 'd';

$config['log_threshold'] = 0;

$config['log_path'] = '';

$config['log_file_extension'] = '';

$config['log_file_permissions'] = 0644;
$config['log_date_format'] = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';

$config['error_views_path'] = '';

$config['cache_path'] = '';

$config['cache_query_string'] = FALSE;

$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
//$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_save_path'] = APPPATH . 'cache';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;

$config['cookie_prefix']    = '';
$config['cookie_domain']    = '';
$config['cookie_path']      = '/';
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
$config['cookie_httponly']  = FALSE;

$config['standardize_newlines'] = FALSE;

$config['global_xss_filtering'] = FALSE;

$config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;
$config['csrf_token_name'] = 'csrf_test_name';
$config['csrf_cookie_name'] = 'csrf_cookie_name';
$config['csrf_expire'] = 7200;
//$config['csrf_regenerate'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_regenerate'] = FALSE;
$config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array();
$config['compress_output'] = FALSE;

$config['time_reference'] = 'local';

$config['rewrite_short_tags'] = FALSE;

$config['proxy_ips'] = '';
```

Comment: show your config/database.php file

Comment: Are you sure your mariadb service is running? is it operating on the default port?

Comment: First 2 hits on Google using "mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002)": [first](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29928109/getting-error-mysqlireal-connect-hy000-2002-no-such-file-or-directory-wh), [second](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13769504/mysqlimysqli-hy000-2002-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-sock). By the looks of those and more results: your config might be incorrect, use `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` for your "hostname". Check DB service is running. Maybe both.

Comment: check your database.php file and set correctly your hostname,database name,username,password

Answer (score 3):

In your database.php instead of putting "`localhost`" try putting "`127.0.0.1`". This works for most of the cases.

If you still get error then post you database.php file.

Answer (score 2):

Use `'hostname' => 'localhost'` instead of `'hostname' => 'testurl.com'`. Even though you upload your code on live server, hostname remains "localhost" only.

Comment: I made 'hostname'=>'localhost' . I still got the same error.

Comment: try using '127.0.0.1' instead of 'localhost' in hostname

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.For local server.

```
$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'      => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => '<user>',
    'password' => '<password>',
    'database' => '<database>',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt'  => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Comment: I have no issue on local server. But when I upload the file on server, then error message "SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused" is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Plese check Your localhost/localserver is start or not, if your server is not started ths problem may be create.
second possiblility is if your please check your credentials in config/database.php   if is incorrect then please correct it..