# How to connect mysql database from linux terminal

Tags: php

I am trying to connect mysql database from Linux server ,it  showing

> warning mysqli_construct() connection refused (HY000/2002)

i dont know why ,please  suggest me a solution for this issue( Actually i am calling a php program which is used for connecting database in Linux mate terminal it shows like this connection refused).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This has been asked before, see: [Getting error mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory when i try to access my project on live server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29928109/getting-error-mysqlireal-connect-hy000-2002-no-such-file-or-directory-wh)

Is MySQL running on the host you are trying to connect to? And are you *sure* about that?

If MySQL is running locally (on localhost), you can connect to it from the command line using:

`mysql -u <db_user> -p <db_name>`

If you get an error running that command, check that MySQL is actually running on your platform.