# Moodle database connection error

Tags: php, moodle

I am trying to setup moodle and running into a connection problem. See the config below:

```
<?php  // Moodle configuration file

unset($CFG);
global $CFG;
$CFG = new stdClass();

$CFG->dbtype    = 'mysqli';
$CFG->dblibrary = 'native';
$CFG->dbhost    = 'localhost';
$CFG->dbname    = 'gs_vle';
$CFG->dbuser    = 'root';
$CFG->dbpass    = 'root';
$CFG->prefix    = 'mdl_';
$CFG->dboptions = array (
 'dbpersist' => 0,
 'dbport' => '',
 'dbsocket' => '',
);

$CFG->wwwroot   = 'http://localhost/~ryanme/work/vle/';
$CFG->dataroot  = '/Users/ryanme/sites/work/moodledata';
$CFG->admin     = 'admin';

$CFG->directorypermissions = 0777;

require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/lib/setup.php');
```

I am getting a database connection error.
See the error below:

```
Error: Database connection failed

It is possible that the database is overloaded or otherwise not running properly.

The site administrator should also check that the database details have been correctly specified in config.php

Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory in /Users/ryanme/Sites/work/vle/lib/dml/mysqli_native_moodle_database.php on line 79
```

Things I have done

- Logged in with the root user via terminal and checked I can see the database with `show databases;`. This works fine.
- Checked the settings are correct over and over.
- Compared the config file to teams setup and it's pretty much the same.
- Ensured the mysqli module is enabled for PHP. It is.

What can I do to figure out what is causing this database connection error?

Comment: is databeas type really mysqli? is this www root correct?

Comment: How do I check that? I would have expected that to be the default for mysql.

Comment: can you load your wwwroot in browser? it has to be the destination of index.php

Comment: Yes. I can navigate to moodle as well and follow the wizard to setup the config file via the front end, but that does not work either.

Comment: ca you access this path? /Users/ryanme/Sites/work/vle/lib/dml/mysqli_native_moodle_database.php if not you have a misconfiguration of your www root / vhost

Comment: yes. This is setup on my localhost so I can see that directory and all the folders in it.

Comment: so if you browse /Users/ryanme/Sites/work/vle/ there is the index.php? remove the ~ maybe

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80584/discussion-between-ryan-neal-mes-and-brandelizer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more investigation. I found that this was due to "mysql on OS X gets the locations of the required sock file a bit wrong". Once I created the sym links required for the mysql sock file everything worked.

See [linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219970/warning-mysql-connect-2002-no-such-file-or-directory-trying-to-connect-vi) issue for details.

Answer (score 0):

I had had the same problem. To solve this issue I put the name of the server instead localhost

`$CFG->dbhost    = '<name-of-the-server>'`;

Answer (score 0):

I got this error after an app installation changed the database password of Moodle. To fix this, I updated the password in Moodle's `config.php` and, sure enough, my problem was resolved.

Perhaps Moodle should have some original database errors, like "database connection failed"? That could save a lot of time, instead of that generic error. Just a suggestion.