# mysqli_connect() error with PHP's built-in web server

Tags: php, mysqli

I compiled PHP with `mysqlnd` using the prescriptions from [Mysqlnd installation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlnd.install.php). PHP works fine. `php -m | grep mysql` shows that neccessary MySQL modules are actually installed.  Then I run `php -S localhost:8088 -t <dir>.` In PHP code `function_exists('mysqli_connect')` does return `true`. But when I run `mysqli_connect()` warning `mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory` arises. In `/etc/php.ini` I set default socket to `/tmp/mysql.sock` then to `/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock`. Both variants didn't work. How can I enable mysql support in PHP-built-in server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried those solutions ?
[Warning: mysql_connect(): [2002] No such file or directory (trying to connect via unix:///tmp/mysql.sock) in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219970/warning-mysql-connect-2002-no-such-file-or-directory-trying-to-connect-vi)

First try to use 127.0.0.1 instead of "localhost" in your mysqli_connect call.

Then make sure there is sockets where it should : make a symbolic link from /tmp/mysql.sock to /var/mysql/mysql.sock (or other way depending what exists on your computer)

Finally try to read all answers listed in the link above, maybe one of them will hel you

Comment: Thanx bar-code. I used your link. Then I went to other links mentioned there , and then to others, trying everything. And the one thing did miracle: I merely copied socket location from MySQL's config file to default sockets in `/etc/php.ini`