# MySQL connection: No such file or directory

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, lamp

I am trying to connect to MySQL on a LAMP instance. If I run

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "pass");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
      die("Connection error: " . $mysqli->connect_error);
}
```

I only receive the connection error

> No such file or directory.

This is the information I get from phpinfo():

[image: phpinfo()]

When I try changing `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` or if I add the port as follows `localhost:3306` or `127.0.0.1:3306` the error changes to 'Connection refused'. The LAMP instance is running on a remote server by my company where I do not have any root access. Do you have an idea what I could do to fix the MySQL connection?

EDIT: This question is not the same as for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219970/warning-mysql-connect-2002-no-such-file-or-directory-trying-to-connect-vi) since I do not have root access on the server where the MySQL instance is on. Therefore I cannot use the regular tricks to check whether `mysql.sock` is in the right place etc. I am pretty sure that the server's settings are correct, I just need help finding out how to write my MySQL-connection correctly.

Comment: I've changed the user and pass in the question to prevent whatever there is to be prevented...

Comment: `No such file or directory.` doesn't seem like a connection error to me.

Comment: _The LAMP instance is running on a remote server_ If you mean that the MySQL that you are trying to connect to is on a remote machine then `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` are not what you want in your connection. They indicate ___the machine I am currently running my PHP code on___

Comment: Or is your code also running on the _Remote Server_?

Comment: In which case, is your MySQL instance on the same machine as your web server and the PHP code

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes, the MySQL instance and the PHP code are on the same server.

Comment: Then it looks like the Dup answer is what you are looking for

Comment: there are *many* answers in the linked thread. try different suggestions. You don't need root privileges to find out the path to mysql socket. if you need to connect with localhost, there are no whatever "correct" credentials other than localhost and 127.0.0.1. Stop blaming everyone else and start looking for the solution.

Comment: This answer appears to be directly applicable to you and doesn't require root permissions. https://stackoverflow.com/a/10958016/310988