# How to enable mysql on legacy PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I have legacy software which cannot be upgraded and I require PHP 5.3 for depreciated functions like mysql_connect() and session_register(). Running Debian 9.5 and lighttpd (can use Apache/nginx if necessary)

PHP doesn't seem to have the mysql extension installed: **Fatal error:** `Call to undefined function mysql_connect()`

I downloaded and compiled PHP 5.3 and here's the [output of phpinfo()](https://screenshots.firefox.com/eM0XJmRuz3QOL3XW/204.44.116.71).

I have php5.6-mysql and php-mysql installed but perhaps it's not compatible or not enabled for 5.3? The installed mysql version is Ver 15.1 MariaDB

I'm at a loss on what else to try or what I can do, any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: If you have the extensions for 5.6, why not use PHP 5.6 and turn off deprecation warnings? (even though I would recommend rewriting the application to use the superior PDO or MySQLi instead, but if it's not an option...)

Comment: Extensions for php5.6 will not work with PHP5.3

Comment: @MagnusEriksson 5.6 doesn't allow for session_register() unfortunately, that was my first venture (mysql worked then). I don't own the source and not authorized to modify it.

Comment: Did you follow the manual for compiling with mysql…? http://php.net/manual/en/mysql.installation.php

Comment: You can also try and run it through Docker.

Comment: @deceze Thanks for that suggestion, I didn't know that I needed to compile with those flags. It sort of works now, thanks! The other issue is now it says: `Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: [2002] No such file or directory (trying to connect via unix:///tmp/mysql.sock). `

Comment: @dukevin this is a different question, so you should not ask it in a comment. Also, you could have searched for the error message, which would have yielded this question on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219970/warning-mysql-connect-2002-no-such-file-or-directory-trying-to-connect-vi Also, pls note that a program written for an old version of MySQL may be in for some nasty surprises if you use a modern version of mariadb. Mariadb was indeed a fork from MySQL, but it has deviated from it . Code that used to run in an old MySQL may not run in mariadb or may produce different results.

Comment: `I don't own the source and not authorized to modify it.` - tell the owner that your price just tripled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer taken from @deceze was that php 5.3 does not come packaged with mysql and must be specified at compile time. `./configure --with-mysql=mysqlnd`

See this for your specific installation: http://php.net/manual/en/mysql.installation.php

Answer (score 0):

Try to download the php5-mysql package and include it in the loaded extensions

Here is a link to it in the debian repo...
https://packages.debian.org/es/sid/php5-mysql

Comment: How do I include it in the loaded extensions? I already do have php5.6-mysql on my system (assuming that is what you linked) and it worked when I had php5.6 but I require 5.3. Not sure if it matters

Comment: sorry discard my answer. I was talking about adding the extension in case it was missing. For 5.3, , the flags for mysql to be included must be added when compiling as dukevin has mentioned above. ./configure --with-mysql=mysqlnd