# Database connection "Mysql" is missing and mysql.sock is missing

Tags: mysql, cakephp, mamp, mysql.sock

I was trying to generate model code from cake command line tool. But got this issue.

```
Warning Error: PDO::__construct(): [2002] No such file or directory (trying to connect via unix:///var/mysql/mysql.sock) in [/Users/test/Google_WWW/project_name/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/Database/Mysql.php, line 177]

Error: Database connection "Mysql" is missing, or could not be created. (although it's showing that mysql database is connected at localhost in cakephp directory)
```

I'm using MAMP.

I searched a lot and found some solutions. For instance,this 
   [CakePHP: No such file or directory (trying to connect via unix:///var/mysql/mysql.sock)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968013/cakephp-no-such-file-or-directory-trying-to-connect-via-unix-var-mysql-mysq?rq=1)

or I can also make a symbolic link of mysql.sock.

```
/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock (not present in directory)
```

But before i do anything, the problem is mysql.sock file isn't present in this directory. I have tried re-installing the MAMP but still no mysql.sock.

Please help me solve this problem ? Can I create my own mysql.sock file..?

Edit: My db config

```
public $default = array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'login' => 'root',
    'password' => 'root',
    'database' => 'db_name',
    'prefix' => ''
);
```

Comment: can you please post your database configuration parameters?

Comment: edited my question, one thing I must say that database is connected without any issues. But for creating model via cakephp cli, it uses mysql.sock that's not present in mamp folder I mentioned.

Comment: what if you try 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost?

Comment: No, still same issue.. Thanks for the reply though !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

MAMP is strange when it comes to mysql. Chances are you need to set up a symbolic link so it knows where to find it. Something like:

`sudo ln -s /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock /tmp/mysql.sock`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did create a symbolic link but my problem wasn't solved.

Comment: To use it with php-cli, after creating the symbolic link, edit your php.ini: `pdo_mysql.default_socket= /tmp/mysql.sock`, `mysql.default_socket = /tmp/mysql.sock`, `mysqli.default_socket = /tmp/mysql.sock`

Comment: the file is not created at all in my case. can you please tell me how to get mamp to generate the file? but phpmyadmin works perfectly fine

Comment: The blog link above does not work. Also this symlink solution is aimed at MAMP, not MAMP PRO

Comment: bravo, your solution really work. i stuck in this problem for almost 2 weeks

Answer (score 4):

After searching and trying a lot of things I finally managed to solve my problem. The answer Chuck Burgess given above could solve the problem, but my scenario was little different that I wasn't able to see mysql.sock file at:

```
    /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
```

I thought my mysql.sock was missing but actually it was there and hidden (THAT's STRANGE! I WENT TO THAT FOLDER using CLI AND SAW THAT). I'm using MAC and files starting with '.' are usually HIDDEN but don't know why mysql.sock was hidden so what I did is in my database configuration file I added 1 parameter (unix_socket) and my problem was solved.

```
   'unix_socket' => '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock'
```

Comment: same here its hidden and can see it via cli. but when i add the unix_socket still i dont get connected.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was because I was calling the wrong version of PHP. I.e. I was using `/usr/bin/php` which when MAMP Pro's php is `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.29/bin/php`

Comment: Man how do you do this

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with this the whole weekend and finally solved it. Turns out that the php.ini is pointing to a non-existing "extensions dir". Create a phpinfo() file and look at the value of this field:
[image: extensions_dir]

I noticed that in the mamp php installed folder there is a no-debug-non-zts-20131226 folder, which is different from the value shown in the phpinfo(). What I did was to clone this folder and changed the name to the value of the phpinfo(). Probably you could modify the php.ini file but I didn't want to.

I see that you solved your problem but mine was different so I'm posting this answer to help future googlers looking for a similar problem.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem appear just after a power outage. So I fixed it by deleting the /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid file and restarting MAMP.

Comment: this broke my mamp :-(

Answer (score 0):

With MAMP create a symbolic link in the folder /var/mysql/:

sudo ln -n /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock /var/mysql/mysql.sock

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here, but managed to resolve it connecting to IP:Port, not socket.

```
'host' => '127.0.0.1', //use 172.0.0.1 instead of localhost
'port' => '8889', //default MAMP MySQL devel port, default production port is 3306
```

and forget about socket connection.