# setting up MySQL Workbench with MAMP - missing 'mysql.sock' file

Tags: mysql, mamp, mysql-workbench

I am having trouble connecting MySQL Workbench to MAMP. I am using version MySQL Workbench version 6.0 and MAMP version 3.0.3.

I have followed the instructions on this link: http://www.rubberneckdesigns.com/mamp/how-to-set-up-mysql-workbench-for-a-mamp-server/comment-page-1/#comment-6539 (this is just basic instructions to setting up MySQL Workbench with MAMP so no need to look through if you are familiar with the set up steps)

It all goes okay until the step were I have to select the Configuration File as:

> /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock

This file does not appear to be in this location or anywhere else on my computer.

In the answer to this link: [Database connection "Mysql" is missing and mysql.sock is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19320563/database-connection-mysql-is-missing-and-mysql-sock-is-missing), he says he managed to figure out that his `mysql.sock` file was actually hidden, however I have my Mac set to display hidden files and I can see all my other hidden files, but still no sign of this file. He said after finding it was hidden he went to his `database configuration file` and added the following:

```
'unix_socket' => '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock'
```

Does anyone know what file he is referring to when he says `database configuration file`? I have tried figuring it out using Google but no luck. I am new to MAMP and new to MySQL Workbench.

This problem with the `mysql.sock` file, seems to be a problem for a lot of people. If anyone has a better solution than adding the above command to the `database configuration file` or can shed some light on this problem I would love to hear it.

Thanks

Comment: Isn't the socket file created dynamically when you open a connection. You just select the location where to put the socket file.

Comment: Mike, thanks for the comment, you are probably right, however my knowledge on MySQL is very limited so I couldn't know for sure. Although I didn't manage to confirm where the MySQL file is or whether it is created once the connection is made, I have solved my problem and explained the solution below. Thanks for taking the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not been able to figure out where the mysql.sock file is, Mike Lischke has left a comment saying the socket file is created dynamically when you open a connection, which could be the case, but I do not know much about MySQL and the files so I can not confirm if this is correct, however, I have found the solution to my problem.

The overall problem was that I could not connect MySQLWorkbench to my Local Server (MAMP) as I could not find the mysql.sock file. When I tried to connect I was getting an error message saying it could not find the mysql.sock file.

The solution to my problem was to instead of setting the 'Hostname' in the MySQLWorkbench set up window as 'localhost', which is suggested in the guide I followed, I instead set it to the IP '127.0.0.1'. I then set the 'Connection Method' to 'Standard (TCP/IP)' instead of 'Local Socket/Pipe'. I believe what this is doing is setting it up to connect through the IP rather than the Socket, meaning the mysql.sock file is no long necessary.

This is a very simple solution and in hindsight it makes sense and I probably should have known this from the start, however because I am new to MySQL I didn't. If anyone else is having a similar problem connecting, I hope this helps.