# Resetting root pw for mySQL

Tags: mysql

I found some instructions online but running into an error:

Following this - [Setting the MySQL root user password on OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6474775/setting-the-mysql-root-user-password-on-os-x)

I ran

```
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
```

The results were:

> 2017-06-28T15:22:12.6NZ mysqld_safe Logging to
>   '/usr/local/var/mysql/Morgans-iMac.local.err'. 2017-06-28T15:22:12.6NZ
>   mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from
>   /usr/local/var/mysql

So it looks like it is running. However when I type in (in a new window):

```
mysql -u root
```

I get the error:

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
>   '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

What am I doing wrong? Is this a pathing problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a symbolic link for the '/tmp/mysql.sock' as it is not present, it is available in a different location where mysql is installed.

It is similar to the following one mentioned in this post,

[Database connection "Mysql" is missing and mysql.sock is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19320563/database-connection-mysql-is-missing-and-mysql-sock-is-missing)

Answer (score 0):

If symbolic link for the '/tmp/mysql.sock' doesn't help you then this is possible permission problem. Try: sudo chmod +t /tmp